# System cron jobs are not running

Tags: python

I am giving using the following command in my /etc/crontab

```
38 05 * * * root /opt/liab-ap/purge.py -psupport --config /opt/liab-ap/liab-ap.cfg "/data/liab-ap/$(date --date '365 days ago' '+%Y%m')" "$(date --date '365 days ago' '+%Y%m%d')*.json.gz" >>/var/log/liab-ap-cron.log 2>&1
```

When I run it manually, the command runs, but not at the specified time.

I have tried putting escape characters before the '%' but that doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than sending `$(date --date '365 days ago' '+%Y%m')" "$(date --date '365 days ago' '+%Y%m%d')` I should remove quotes and place escape sequences before the `%` character, like so:

```
$(date --date '365 days ago' +\%Y\%m)" "$(date --date '365 days ago' +\%Y\%m\%d)
```

Hope this will be useful to someone:)

Comment: As a general practice, and to improve maintainability and readability, I typically put extensive commands like this in a short shell script, and then make cron run the shellscript.